# Java application UI layout

Tags: java, swing

Alright, basically I have this java program and I want to have a home screen of sorts. I want to be able to see the current progress in a scroll pane of sorts that has multiple panels that can be added and removed. These panels will contain a progress bar and a cancel button as well as a label to identify the task. How would I go about adding and removing these panels to this scroll pane? Should I have one panel and create the task progress panels within it? Would I be able to "stack" them vertically as I add them, with the oldest panel at the bottom?

Some help would be appreciated. I was thinking maybe a JTable with a custom cell editor, but it doesn't allow very big panels to be created. Should I go further and make a custom JTable class of sorts, and JList can have a bigger panel size but they are only painted and not intractable.

So as I said, any help would be appreciated. Please and thank you.

Comment: What have you mocked up so far?  Sometimes trial by fire is your best friend.

Comment: You might want to read over some other StackOverflow questions and improve yours, such as by giving it a more useful title.  Good luck!

Comment: Yea, I realize the title is vague but I didn't know how I wanted it worded. And I haven't tried anything except a custom JList renderer when I realized it was only rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Going with your original JPanel idea, you can have a scroll pane with a panel inside it. Then, you can create panels with your data and add the new panels to the main panel in the scroll pane. Your main JPanel (the one in the scroll pane) should use a BoxLayout with a vertical alignment, this will stack panels on top of each other.

If you want to use a JTable you can, and change the cells to a JTextArea instead of a JTextField. It's doable, but I'd have to dig up some old code to figure out how again.